# Let $ O_{p^{\prime}}(G/A) = T/A $, Why $ T \leq F $ and $ [A , T]=? $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ be a soluble group and $ A $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $,where $ A $ is an elementary abelian group of prime power order. Let each chief factor of $ G/A $ has order $ 4 $ or a prime and $ A $ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $ G $. Let $ N = Fit(G) $. then $ N = O_{p}(G) $. Let $ F/N = O_{p^{\prime}}(G/N) $, then $ F>N $. Let $ F = VN $ that $ V \cap N = 1 $ . Let $ L = N_{G}(V) $. Then $ G = LN $. Suppose $ A \leq L $, then $ [A , V] = ?$

Let $ O_{p^{\prime}}(G/A) = T/A $, Why $ T \leq F $ and $ [A , T]=? $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A \le L$ then $[A,V] \le A \cap V = 1$.

$T/A = TA/A \cong T/T \cap A$ is a $p'$-group hence so is $T/T \cap N \cong TN/N$ so $T \le F$.

Since $A$ is minimal normal, $[T,A] = 1$ or $A$. If $[T,A]=1$ then $A \le Z(T)$ and $T = A \times B$ with $B$ a $p'$-group and $B \unlhd G$. So, since $A$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup, $B=1$ and $T=A$. So either $T=A$ or $[T,A]=A$.

Comment: $ [T , A] = 1 $ is false?

Comment: and by which theorem $ T = A \times B $?

Comment: $A$ has a complement $B$ in $T$ by Schur-Zassenshaus, and then $A \le Z(T) \Rightarrow T=A \times B$. I think you could have $B=1$ and in that case $T=A$ and $[T,A]=1$. Otherwise $[T,A]=A$.